# Vue.js - prop not reactive when initialized via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-props, vue-reactivity

I have a parent component (*item-list*) to which I pass items from a PHP view (Laravel/Blade). The item-list consists of *list-items* (child component). Inside a list-item I want to modify/delete this specific item. After triggering the deletion inside the child component, an event will be emitted back to parent component where the item will be finally removed from the items list.

It seems like this approach is not reactive. If I instead use `data()` with some dummy data for the list items of a prop filled via PHP, it's reactive.

How can I guarantee reactivity for `props` passed via PHP?

**Parent component:**

```js
    <template>
    
      <my-list-item
        v-for="item of items"
        :key="item.id"
        :item="item"
        @remove="removed"
      ></my-list-item>
      <br />
    
    
    </template>
    
    <script>
    
    import MyListItem from './my-list-item'
    
    export default {
    
      // parent component
      name: "my-list",
      components: {
        MyListItem
      },
    
      data() {
        return {
    
          // this will work. items are reactive
    
          // items: [
          //
          //   { id: 1, message: 'foo' },
          //   { id: 2, message: 'bar' },
          //
          // ]
        }
      },
    
      props: {
    
        // not reactive, items come from PHP view (Laravel/Blade).
        items: {
          type: Array,
          default: undefined
        }
      },
      methods: {
        removed: function (item) {
          _.remove(this.items, item);
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

**Child component:**

```js
<template>

  <!-- item stuff here (label, etc.)
    ...
  -->

  {{ item.message }}

  <!-- remove link -->
  <a href="#" @click="remove(item)">remove</a>
</template>

<script>

// child
export default {
  name: "my-list-item",

  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
    }
  },

  emits: [
    'remove'
  ],

  methods: {

    remove: function (item) {
      this.$emit("remove", item);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**PHP view (list.blade.php):**

```php
@extends('dashboard')
@section('title', 'List items')

@section('content')
  <my-list :items="{{ Session::get('items') }}"></my-list>
@endsection
```

Comment: you shouldn't mutate props, though it's unclear from your snippets where and how PHP is passing the prop

Comment: Thx. I've added the PHP side to my question. I'm using the component inside a Laravel/Blade view. There I pass the data to the items-prop.

Comment: ok, you should not mutate props regardless, pass it in like your doing then clone/copy it to a value in data then it will be reactive

Comment: Sounds plausible. Thanks.

Comment: if you were doing `<my-list :items="items"></my-list>` and items was set in data in the parent, ie `data: => ({items: {{ Session::get('items') }}})` then it would have [Vue.observable](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) added to it (its reactivity), passing a basically hardcoded object literal / json to the prop cuts that out

Comment: Many thanks Lawrence. I'll check this.